# Microsoft SSRS 2016 - publish report header and report footer as Report Parts

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, header, footer, ssrs-2016

I have used Microsoft SSRS extensively with the Report Manager.

Today I have a unique requirement:

I need to deploy the header and footer of a report as Report Part. (I am completely new to report parts though)

After building the report in SSRS 2016 Report Designer, I go to the tab Reports, and choose Publish Report Parts.

In the Publish Report Parts tab, I see **Select items to Publish**.

In this window, I do NOT see the report header or footer.  I see only the parameters used in the report.

When I use the SSRS Report Builder to **Publish Report Parts**, I see parameters and datasets (this time), but still not the header or footer.

Any idea on how to publish the header and footer alone as Report Part ?

Comment: that means you want header and Fotter in your report ?  Or You want to only Header + Footer ( without middle part) report ?

Comment: I want header alone as one report part; footer alone as another report part